# Filter files in all subdirectories and save them with the same name?

Tags: linux, shell, filter, command, text-files

How to remove duplicate lines in every file in directory and save the fixed data in the same file  with a single line command ?

the following do not work :

```
   find . -type f -execdir cat {} | sort | uniq > {} \; 

   find . -type f | xargs -I{} cat {} | sort | uniq > {}

   find . -type f | xargs -I{} cat {} | sort | uniq > {}.new && mv {}.new {}
```

the '>' symbol breaks the chain ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a shell wrapper in the exec:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'sort "$1" | uniq > "$1.new" && mv "$1.new" "$1"' _ {} \;
```